# mmap() keeps returning MAP_FAILED whe trying to read or write to a PIO address on cyclone V FPGA

Tags: c, fpga, mmap

I am trying to write an integer (1114129) from my HPS on **Cyclone V Altera FPGA** from a **PUTTY** window to a 32bit PIO on the FPGA side via lightweight axis interface. I am using mmap() and cannot get it to work, have been trying for months.

I have set up the hardware side correctly because I was able to read from another 32bit PIO at the address 0xff205000, this works fine but I can't read or write to the second PIO. I have tried multiple different addresses as well and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is the error I get, which is because of mmap returns `MAP_FAILED`

```
open /dev/mem successfully !
npheap_alloc(): Invalid argument
#
```

As you can see above the file is opened correctly and then it fails on the mmap call.

Below is the c code im using. There are no compiling issues.
If anyone could help or even point me in the right direction i would be really appreciative its driving me insane.

```
#define MAPPED_SIZE 4

#define DDR_RAM_PHYS 0xff205010

int main(void)


{

        int _fdmem;
        void *map;

        const char memDevice[] = "/dev/mem";
        _fdmem = open( memDevice, O_RDWR | O_SYNC );

        if (_fdmem < 0){
                printf("Failed to open the /dev/mem !\n");
                return 0;
        }
        else{
                printf("open /dev/mem successfully !\n");
        }

        /* mmap() the opened /dev/mem */
        map = mmap(0, MAPPED_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, _fdmem, DDR_RAM_PHYS);




          if (map == MAP_FAILED) { perror("npheap_alloc()"); exit(1); }

        *(unsigned int*)(map+(0xff205010)) = (unsigned short)1114129;
        //int *q = (int *)map;
        //*q = 1114129;



        /* unmap the area & error checking */
        if (munmap(map,MAPPED_SIZE)==-1){
               perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        }



        /* close the character device */
        close(_fdmem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`0xff205010` is not a valid `mmap` offset: it's not page-aligned. Also, adding `0xff205010` to map would not be valid even if it were; map would already refer to that physical address.

Instead, You need to `mmap` the correct page (`0xff205010 & -PAGESIZE`) then use (`0xff205010 % PAGESIZE`) as the offset into the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, how do I find out the correct page? And where you say I need to mmap the correct page would that mean changing the DDR_RAM_PHYS from current value to a new defined value? Or do I add the ‘&’ sign after like this map = mmap(0, MAPPED_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, _fdmem, DDR_RAM_PHYS & -pagesize);?
Do you know of any good sources of information I can read regarding this topic?

Comment: @Jacko123: Exactly what you wrote there in the comment. The `&` masks off bits, and since `PAGESIZE` is a power of 2 (typically `0x1000`), `-PAGESIZE` is a mask to remove all the lower bits - assuming unsigned 64-bit type and 4k pages, `-PAGESIZE` is `0xfffffffffffff000`. If `PAGESIZE` is not constant for the arch, you get it via `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.